# How to zip a folder and all of its files in Python, while preserving the folder name and relative paths for its contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, shutil

I am trying to create a backup script in Python 3.5 that will zip all the contents of a specified folder. Here is what I am doing now:

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os
import os.path

import dropbox


INPUT_FOLDER = '~/Documents/db-backup-test/'
ARCHIVE_PATH = '~/Documents/tmp/'
ARCHIVE_FILE_NAME = "db-backup_iOS__"


def compress_folder(origem, destino):
    try:
        arq = shutil.make_archive(destino, 'zip', root_dir=origem, base_dir=origem)
    except Exception as e:
        print('\n\nAn error was found during compression:')
        print(e)


timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())
input_path = os.path.expanduser(INPUT_FOLDER)
archive_path = os.path.expanduser(ARCHIVE_PATH + ARCHIVE_FILE_NAME + timestamp)

compress_folder(input_path, archive_path)
```

I goes well, except for one thing: the resulting zip archive extracts its contents with a reproduction of the full original path. What I would like is to get is a simple copy of the folder, with its original name and its contents with relative paths, when extracting the archive.

I was looking into a simple and short solution that would not require to iterate through the folder contents.

Is this possible with `shutil.make_archive()`, or will I need to dig into other modules, like `zipfile`?

Comment: This is because you set `base_dir` to be the same as `root_dir`. `base_dir` defines the path for the archived files: _"base_dir is the directory where we start archiving from; ie. base_dir will be the common prefix of all files and directories in the archive."_ So you need to _unset_ `base_dir`.

Comment: I tried that, but then the folder itself is extracted with the name of the archive file, not the name of the original folder, which is what I need here. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Did you try passing `db-backup-test` as your `base_dir`?

Comment: I was expecting to have a built-in way to include the original folder name. But now I think understand better the concept of base_dir. So I could extract the name of the folder that will be compressed and then feed that as the base_dir. I will try that.

Comment: Well, I just tried `base = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(origem))` and then using that `base` variable as the base_dir, but I get an error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db-backup-test'". Maybe it is somehow looking inside db-backup-test trying to find a similarly named folder...?

Answer (score 0):

Use the arcname parameter to control the name/path in the zip file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import zipfile

def zip(src, dst):
   zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
   abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
   for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
       for filename in files:
          absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
          arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
          print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename), arcname)
          zf.write(absname, arcname)
   zf.close()
zip("src", "dst")
```

With a directory structure like this:

```
src
└── a
    ├── b
    │   └── bar
    └── foo
```

Comment: This should be a comment, unless an example code is shown in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am working only with Python 3, however. I understand that the zip file module allows more fine control, but I am looking for the simplest solution for this task. I would really prefer something that fits in less lines with no for loops, unless I have a good reason to go with a longer code.